# Extend JavaScript object prototype by typescript class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, prototype, angular-http

> **tl;dr:** I need to have the compiled Typescript prototype definitions applied to objects I have defined to be of that class.

---

**Situation:**
I need to extend a JavaScript object by some business logic defined in a typescript class.
This might look somewhat like:

```
class Address
{
  constructor(
    public Street: string,
    public Number: number,
    public Zip: number,
    public City: string)
  { }

  public get FullAddress()
  {
    return this.Street + ' ' + this.Number + ', '
      + this.Zip + ' ' + this.City;
  }
}
```

The compiled JS adds the code to extend the object prototype by `FullAddress`. If I call `new Address('Somestreet', 5, 3564, 'SomeCity')` everything works like a charm.

---

**The Problem:** when I get some JS object (in my case using angular's `$http`)

```
$http.get('/api/address').then((answer: AngularPromise<Address[]>) => 
{
  console.log(answer.data[0].FullAddress());
});
```

I can call the function `FullAddress` on the object since in Typescript the function is defined on the class definition.

Now when I execute the code in the browser `answer.data.FullAddress()` is not defined (which makes sense since Typescript just provides the type definition and never touched the object.

---

**Attempted Solution**: One possible solution would be calling the constructor for each object (somewhat like following)

```
$http.get('/api/address').then((answer: AngularPromise<Address[]>) => 
{
  for(var i = 0; i < answer.data.length; i++)
  {
    answer.data[0] = new Address(answer.data[0].Street, ans.....);
  }
  console.log(answer.data[0].FullAddress());
});
```

and maybe overload the `Address` constructor to accept the complete object to reduce boilerplate.

---

**The actual Question:** Since the Object I need is a way more complex nested structure than that simple Address construct described here, above solution would require me to write an enormous amount of boilerplate and I feel like there has to be a better solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue! One way to go, as you said is to make a constructor and feed all the info in - a bit tedious and seems wrong. We ended up making a `MapTo` function that can map a generic object to a strong class:

```
public static MapTo(jsonObject, nameSpace, classType) {
    var instance = new classType();
    for (var prop in jsonObject) {
        if (!jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (jsonObject[prop] == null) {
            instance[prop] = null;
        } else if (typeof jsonObject[prop] === 'object') {
            if (nameSpace[prop]) {
                instance[prop] = this.MapTo(jsonObject[prop], nameSpace, nameSpace[prop]);
            } else {
                instance[prop] = jsonObject[prop];
            }
        } else {
            instance[prop] = jsonObject[prop];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
var strongAddress = MapTo(answer.data[0], Models, Models.Address); //I assumed your class was in a namespace called "Models"
```

Comment: Interesting approach... still feels a bit wonky but already way better.  

My problem with that: I fear it only works on internal modules, right (since I use my classes in Angular and on NodeJS I use external modules only :| )